# Square wave rectified output value calculation

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider, rectifier, wave, square

[image: Using a wireless osc (hand osc)]
I can understand the ground osc probe but with a hand osc I shouldn´t have that problem, I think.

But It went even worst. Maybe it is a doubler¿?

Comment: Hi there! Instead of adding new information in form of answers, can you edit the pictures into your question instead you think? They will be removed anyway in time.

Comment: And for clarity, you can add the oscilloscope reading and the voltage divicer circuit as two pictures.

Comment: So you have a voltage divider formed by 3 of 15k resistors, and you are measuring the waveform across one of them using the scope? With voltmeter you are measuring the output of bridge (not across one resistor but the entire output)? Did I understand correct?

Comment: With voltmeter I am measuring DC lines, just before the Inverter.

Comment: You should be using a differential input not a normal scope input.

Comment: There's something wrong with either the circuit or the measurement. With 320V bus rail and full bridge configuration you can get a pulse waveform swinging between ±320V with almost zero (or negligible) offset. Your measurement of 1/3 of the output has an offset of -40V i.e. 50V positive swing and -130V negative swing. Multiply this by 3 and the negative swing hits -390V which is not possible. There's something wrong.

Comment: Remember that the scope ground lead is connected to earth ground. If other parts of your circuit are connected to earth ground, your scope ground is creating paths you don't want. Best case, weird readings. Worst case, big boom. Don't connect the ground, use 2 probes with scope math to subtract them.

Comment: @XanDasXuras Please edit your questions don't post in the answers section